# Using a php for loop how to i substr Thursday to a two letter abbreviation?

Tags: php

I'm already substr all the days to 1 letter but I would like only Thursday to be two letters, right now my loop skips weekends and functions properly for a two week out period from today's date.

```
$lastmonday=strtotime("-".(date("N")-1)." days");
$end=strtotime("+14 days", $lastmonday); 
$datestr = "";

for($i = 1; $i < 14; $i++)
    {
    $curr = strtotime("+".$i." days");
    $weekday = date("N", $curr);

    if ($weekday > 5) continue;

    $datestr .= "sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='$i' then 1 else 0 end)
        '" . substr(date('D', $curr), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('n/j', $curr) . "',";
    }
```

The problem is Monday - Friday are all being substr to 1. Still new to substr and i know it's very useful. Additionally, I'm just not sure how i can stop the loop at Wednesday and substr Thursday to two letters and than back to one letter for Friday.

Would i break the loop and than use the control structure "continue" again, like i'm doing for the $weekday variable?

Comment: Just add a quick if statement in your loop.  `if the day is thursday, substr to two letters`.  You won't need an else statement or anything, because it will only do thursday and keep moving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test the day to see how many characters to grab.

```
substr(date('D', $curr), 0, ($weekday == 4 ? 2 : 1))
```

Comment: I didn't think to use the ternary operator that gives me great ideas. That didn't work though.

Comment: Edit: You might have needed to wrap it in `()`. Also, I don't know the value of $weekday - it may not have been an int so the `===` comparison may have failed. I relaxed it.

Comment: It worked that time, it needed to be Equal and not identical. Thanks for your help Xeoncross.

Comment: === the type must be equal maybe comparing a string to an int? Perhaps that's why it didn't work?